# How to customise scene size in SpriteKite using initWithSize

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I need to lay a new scene on top of the old one, so that an upper band of the old one remains visible at the top. How should I modify initWithSize below?

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    self = [super initWithSize:size];

    if (self) 
{
//code
}

}
```

I tried using:

```
self = [super initWithSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height +30)];
```

instead of

```
self = [super initWithSize:size];
```

but it doesn't work. It simply compresses vertically the scene a bit, but I still cannot see the underlying old scene. Cheers.

Comment: You can't have two or more scene to the same `SKView`.You can have one `SKScene` per `SKView`

Comment: You can have two SKViews though where each one presents separate scene. Still, I would say, you should consider using multiple nodes, rather than multiple scenes.